# Can dependabot suggest patches for direct dependency?

Tags: node.js, security, github, npm, dependabot

Currently, dependabot suggests only the vulnerable package patch version(fix) but If I need to upgrade only the direct dependency which consumes the fix.

- Is that possible with dependabot?
- Is this feature part of the backlog?

Comment: What you are looking for is not supported by `dependabot` yet.

Answer (score 1):

No, Dependabot checks whether it's possible to upgrade the vulnerable dependency to a fixed version without disrupting the dependency graph for the repository. Then Dependabot raises a pull request to update the dependency to the minimum version that includes the patch.